# Convert complex json to dataset

Tags: r, json

I have a problem with converting complex JSON to Dataset such as:

```
[{
    "dateTime": 1556368322971,
    "eventName": "sampleEvent",
    "vars": [{
        "distance": 350,
        "fuel" : 300,
        "vehicleType": null
    }]
}, {
    "dateTime": 1556368322971,
    "eventName": "sampleEvent",
    "vars": [{
        "distance": 360,
        "fuel" : 290,
        "vehicleType": "bus"
    }]
}]
```

I was already trying do this with method:

```
result <- fromJSON(file = "./all.json")


json_file <- lapply(result, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
})
```

But the problem is that all NULL values are missing. This is very problematic, beause when I am converting it to dataSet(matrix) all values are completely in mess and there are no null values which is incorrect.

I expect to have one dataSet which should looks like:

```
dateTime      | eventName   | distance | fuel | vehicleType
1556368322971 | sampleEvent | 350      | 300  | NA
1556368322971 | sampleEvent | 360      | 290  | bus
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `map` family from `purrr` and chain together flattening one level at a time.  Just paying attention to the conflict between `purrr` and `jsonlite` for `flatten`.

```
library(purrr)

# This is how I imported your example JSON
result <- fromJSON("~/Desktop/test.JSON", simplifyVector = F)

# Note that I set simplifyVector = F so that a list is returned

result2 <- result %>%
  map(purrr::flatten) %>% 
  map(purrr::flatten) %>% 
  map_dfr(purrr::flatten)

print(result2)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
       dateTime eventName   distance  fuel vehicleType
          <dbl> <chr>          <int> <int> <chr>      
1 1556368322971 sampleEvent      350   300 NA         
2 1556368322971 sampleEvent      360   290 bus
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get an `Error: .x must be a list (double)`

Comment: yes - there's a function conflict between `purrr`& `jsonlite` for `flatten`. I'll update.

Comment: I still get the same error with `result %>% map(purrr::flatten)`

Comment: Did you set the simplify vector to false in the fromJSON call?

Comment: All of answers where correct, but in your method I have no splitting rows. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @nycrefugee Oh I see, I missed that bit. Still, this seems to be an unnecessarily convoluted (an un-tidy) solution involving many `flatten` calls; it's a one-liner using `unnest` and in base R. But ok, this isn't code-golfing...

Answer (score 4):

We can use `tidyr::unnest`

```
library(tidyr)
result %>% unnest()
#      dateTime   eventName distance fuel vehicleType
#1 1.556368e+12 sampleEvent      350  300        <NA>
#2 1.556368e+12 sampleEvent      360  290         bus
```

---

### Sample data

```
library(jsonlite)
result <- fromJSON("all.json")
```

where file `all.json` contains

```
[{
    "dateTime": 1556368322971,
    "eventName": "sampleEvent",
    "vars": [{
        "distance": 350,
        "fuel" : 300,
        "vehicleType": null
    }]
}, {
    "dateTime": 1556368322971,
    "eventName": "sampleEvent",
    "vars": [{
        "distance": 360,
        "fuel" : 290,
        "vehicleType": "bus"
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

An option with `base R` would be

```
cbind(result[1:2], do.call(rbind, result$vars))
#     dateTime   eventName distance fuel vehicleType
#1 1.556368e+12 sampleEvent      350  300        <NA>
#2 1.556368e+12 sampleEvent      360  290         bus
```